# Get string after a delimiter to the end of line

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get a string after a delimiter to the end of line with PHP and preg_match. These are my codes:

```
<?php
$stringa = <<<EOT
var1=Ciao
var2=Variabile
var3=We
EOT;
preg_match("#var2=(.*?)\n#", $stringa, $boh);
print_r($boh);
?>
```

This works, but not for the last line, if I replace **var2** with **var3** in the regex the generated array will be empty.

Comment: Can someone explain the semantics of the question mark in `(.*?)` I know `?` means "optional", as in `{0,1}` or `(xxx|)`, but I've never seen it used following a `*`. Does it apply to the entire expression of `.*`?  If so, isn't it redundant, since `*` can match 0 occurrences?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin - The `?` can follow any quantifier to make that quantifier _non-greedy_. (You can look up the term.) In short, it instructs the quantifier to match _as few instances as possible_ (as opposed to _as many instances as possible_, which is the default behavior). For example, `*?`, `+?`, `??`, `{2,5}?`, are all non-greedy versions of the respective quantifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use alternation:

```
#var2=(.*?)(\n|$)#
           ^  ^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, before I used this version but with [\n|$] instead of (\n|$), my bad!

Answer (score 3):

Use *multi-line* mode, the `m` modifier, so that `$` matches a newline or the end of string:

```
preg_match('#var2=(.*?)$#m', $stringa, $boh);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you need a newline after the "We" to match properly:

```
<?php
$stringa = <<<EOT
var1=Ciao
var2=Variabile
var3=We

EOT;
preg_match("#var3=(.*?)\n#", $stringa, $boh);
print_r($boh);
?>
```

Comment: Isn't there already a `\n` after the "We" because the "EOT" appears on the following line? Are are you saying that the regex will only work if there are two consecutive `\n`s at the end?

Comment: The newline used to put EOT on a separate line does not make it into the string.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. I guess that makes sense, as there's no way to terminate the string without a line ending otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the dot, you can use `[^\n]` that exclude all newlines:

```
preg_match('~(?<=var3=)[^\n]+~', $stringa, $boh);
```